# Python fails after deleting site.py

Tags: python, setuptools

### tl;dr

I accidentally deleted my Python installation’s `site.py` file. Now, when trying to start Python, it complains,

> ImportError: Couldn't find the real 'site' module

I tried downloading a `site.py` from [setuptools](http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/branches/setuptools-0.6/site.py) but this results in an infinite recursion in the `__boot` method around the statement `imp.load_module('site',stream,path,descr)` (line 37).

**Is there a way to fix this *without* reinstalling Python? What is the `site.py` file supposed to do?**

### Some background information:

This is on a Linux server with a custom Python installation in my home directory (`~/nfs`, to be precise). There are other Python installations on the server (not mine – it’s a mess!) but `$PATH` and `$PYTHONPATH` are set up in such a way as to find my installation first.

As to why I deleted the `site.py` file: I tried executing a setuptools `setup.py` script and the script told me to delete the file because it “was not created by setuptools”. I foolishly complied.

I suspect that this original error message was caused by the fact that the setuptools implementation is *not* mine.

Comment: As for setuptools; presumably it has it's *own* site.py module within the setuptools package..

Comment: @Martijn It does, that was the one I copied there and which recurses infinitely. Unfortunately, I cannot even install my own setuptools since that yields the same (original) error.

Comment: Note: You do not need a `$PYTHONPATH` env var *usually*. Your own python will find it's own path, but if there are other Python installations listed in `$PYTHONPATH` things tend to get ugly fast.

Comment: @Martijn Yes I know, unfortunately I need it to manage modules that are unrelated to my installation. But I hope to get rid of it one of these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`site` module](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) sets up your python module search path and some other things. It is somewhat crucial to the normal operation of python.

You can download a new copy from the python source repository:

- For [python 2.7](http://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/4f891f44ec15/Lib/site.py)
- For [python 3.2](http://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/f86df559319d/Lib/site.py)

For other python versions, generally the URL is `http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/*major*.*minor*/Lib/site.py` for the correct tagged version, then select the `raw` link in the left-hand menu.

If you installed python from a linux distribution package on Ubuntu or Debian, then this file has been customized and you'll need to re-install the appropriate python-minimal package.

Comment: Awesome. That was it. Now I’m back to square one but that’s a story for another day.

Comment: Is this still true? I'm [getting what seems to be different behavior(http://stackoverflow.com/q/26451807/656912).

Comment: It is still true. What does `import site; print(site)` produce as output?