# Python's 'site.py' gone after Yosemite upgrade. Is that okay?

Tags: python, import, pythonpath, osx-yosemite

The Yosemite (OS X 10.10) upgrade includes Python 2.7.6, and the process, as usual with Apple system updates, seems to completely replace the system packages directory, in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

This time, the process appears to have entirely omitted [`site.py`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html). My understanding was that [this file was essential to the functioning of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11410874/656912), in particular, the proper construction of package search paths; but my Python (which uses nothing more than the Apple system Python and additional packages in `site-packages`) works fine, and [my paths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21236384/656912) remain as they were before the upgrade.

Is `site.py` no longer needed for proper functioning of Python? Has it been moved to another location?

Comment: Do you have a site-packages and site-python folder?  I assume you have done a search for the file as well?

Comment: @DuckPuncher: I have a site-packages folder (where I install all my packages): no site.py there. Where would I find "site-python"?

Comment: I'm reading from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html).  It looks like when python initializes, site.py appends those folders to `sys.path` along with other folders?  Unless I'm reading it incorrectly, it sounds like if `sys.path` contains the paths to those folders it means that `site.py` is running when a program is initialized.

Comment: @DuckPuncher: But that still seems to require a `site.py` (somewhere), which I can no longer find. (Using the [`-S` option](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) omits my home directory and my `site-packages`, so the "automatic import" makes a difference; which implies that *something* is being imported.)

Comment: Don't use the `-S` option.  If you import `sys` and run `sys.path`, does the path to the `site-packages` folder show up?

Comment: @DuckPuncher: Yes. (For reference, with `-S` it does not).

Comment: @raxacoricofalapatorius, Ok, because in the documentation on `site.py` it looks like `site.py` is run when a program initializes, it adds the path to the `site-packages` folder to `sys.path`, so it sounds like `site.py` exists somewhere.  As far as finding it, that is something I can't help with.  But if python works as it did before and your paths aren't affected, then it's probably safe to assume `site.py` exists.  Especially if using the `-S` option omits those filepaths from `sys.path` since that is the expected behaviour.

Comment: @DuckPuncher: Agreed. I wonder where it is (I have no `site-python` folder that I can see.)

Comment: I don't see one in my `sys.path` either.  That might be for older versions of python.  I have never heard of it before looking at the `site.py` docs.

Comment: @DuckPuncher: Must be. Still mystified why it all works (but at least it does!). Weirdly, using `python -m` reveals that neither [`USER_BASE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.USER_BASE) nor [`USER_SITE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE) exist, yet still it all works (or appears to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`site.py` is *still used*. You are just not looking in the right location:

```
>>> import site
>>> print site.__file__
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.pyc
```

The `/Extras` structure appears to consist entirely of *non-standard-library packages*, e.g. packages that Apple installs for their own uses that are not included with standard Python.

If there *was* a `site.py` file there in previous OS X versions it was in all likelihood [one installed by `setuptools`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26035458); with 10.10 comes `setuptools` 1.1.6, which has long since got rid of the hack embodied in that file.

Comment: Excellent! And that (I assume) I should never touch!

Comment: And [a related follow-on about `USER_SITE`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26454521/656912).

Comment: And: I assume the `site.py` that was in '../Extras/lib/python' was old and/or unused (or at least un-necessary, since Apple got rid of it as part of the Yosemite update). Correct?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: older versions of setuptools included a [very hacky `site.py` file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715039/python-interplay-between-lib-site-packages-site-py-and-lib-site-py/26035458#26035458), that is no longer needed and no longer present in current `setuptools` versions. Since Apple now ships wih `setuptools` version 1.1.6 I strongly suspect that you saw the setuptools `site.py` file here. So no, if you saw a `site.py` file there it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

If the behaviour of python hasn't changed and `sys.path` contains the path to your `site-packages` folder, you should be fine.  If you use the interpreters `-S` option, the path to the `site-packages` folder won't show up in `sys.path`, so you can test it.  I would recommend searching for the file on your system.  If it doesn't show up, make sure you can see hidden files in case it's hidden for some reason.

[site.py docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html)

edit:  Resolved in comments, but wanted to provide an official answer.